# Is there a way in Scala to escape multiple return statements without using if nesting

Tags: scala, functional-programming, return

I am new to **Scala**. I have an operation that requires check preconditions before execution.

```
def get(a: Option[A], b: Option[B], c: Option[C]): (Option[Error], Option[String]) = {
    if (a.isEmpty)
        return (Some(Error), None)

    if (b.isEmpty)
        return (Some(Error), None)

    val ab = a.get + b.get
    if (ab < null)
        return (Some(Error), None)

    // Some complex computations 
    (None, Some(str))
}
```

Since I don't like nesting if blocks, I wonder if there is a better way to structure this code, to exclude return statements, and if blocks nesting.

Comment: You also should avoid calling `Option.get`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I suggest to change the return type to Either[Error, String].

Then I'm not sure this sytle is better or not.

```
def get(a: Option[A], b: Option[B], c: Option[C]): Either[Error, String] = {
  val result = for {
    va <- a
    vb <- b
    ab = va * vb
    if ab > 10
  } yield {
    "complex code"
  }

  result map { Right(_) } getOrElse Left(error)
}
```

Comment: No need for semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach:

```
def get(a: Option[A], b: Option[B], c: Option[C]) = (a, b) match {
    case (None, _) => (Some(Error), None)
    case (_, None) => (Some(Error), None)
    case (Some(av), Some(bv)) if (av + bv < null) => (Some(Error), None)
    case _ => 
        // Some complex computations 
        (None, Some(str))
}
```

Could be cleaned up further if one use Either, as @TimGreen has showed in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Tim Green's answer:

```
def get(a: Option[A], b: Option[B], c: Option[C]): Either[Error, String] = (a, b) match {
    case (Some(a), Some(b)) if a + b < 0 =>
      Right("complex code")
    case _ =>
      Left(Error)
}
```

He's completely right about the return type. `(Option[Error], Option[String])` has 4 cases: `(Some(...), Some(...))`, `(Some(...), None)`, etc. You only ever return 2 of them which very strongly suggests this is the wrong type. Also, all of your functions callers either have to handle all 4 cases or know from documentation or from looking at the implementation that 2 of them are used and handle only them, in which case when the implementation changes they will get errors at the run-time.